# Logback separation by Spring Boot child() contexts

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, spring-integration, logback

I am creating **child()** contexts dynamically in Spring Boot and I would like to log each context to a separated file. Is this possible?

The reason to do that is because I have a dynamic spring-integration configuration for different adapters. This is quite useful for working with different connections with the same adapter configuration but there is much information for just one log file.

I saw a Thread separation even a JNDI context separation but I do not know what is the best way to do this. Is this possible just configuring the logback.xml file?

**Update:**

Maybe the option is MDC and I am not understanding the concept. For instance, could you explain how to apply MDC for a Spring `@MessageEndpoint` element with multiple Spring Integration elements such as `@Transformer`, `@ServiceActivator` and `@Router` like the following one:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class TestComponents {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

@Router(inputChannel = "inputRouter")
public MessageChannel router(Message<String> demo) {
..
LOGGER.trace(“TEST”);
…
LOGGER.error(“TEST”);
…
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="inputService")
public void service(Message< String > demo) {   
..
LOGGER.trace(“TEST”);
..
}

@Transformer(inputChannel="inputTransformer", outputChannel="outputTransformer")
public byte[] transformerToByte(Message<String> demo) { 
..
LOGGER.debug(“TEST”);
..
}
}
```

The example could be also applicable to a `@Component` with different methods.

I am worry about performance due to the [paragraph](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) described in the documentation:

> Please note that MDC as implemented by logback-classic assumes that
>   values are placed into the MDC with moderate frequency

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done easily. I don't have a lot of experience with Logback, but I'm quite familiar with Log4J, Spring, Tomcat and classloading.

Logback, like log4J uses a static factory method to produce a singleton logger, this means that static state is stored in the class loader. 
In spring you can specify which class load is used to load the context, but a class loader will only load a class/resource that can't be loaded by the parent class loader (you will discover this if you override URLClassLoader.getResource). This is a problem because when Spring Boot start, logging is initialised and loaded by the 'root' class loader.

The only way I can see you preventing this is to remove the logback jar from your classpath, and create a new URL class loader (containing only the logback jar and configuration) for loading the root Spring context and another class load for loading the child contexts (same jar different configuration). Since the logback jar is not part of the system classpath, you should be able to have two separate logback configuration, because static is scoped by class loaders.

**EDIT**

Diving a little deeper I noticed that it is not enough to have a class loader that loads logback-core and logback-classic jars, due to the way the LoggingSystem class is initialised (LogSystem line 126, version 1.4.1), the entire spring-boot jar (and potentially every thing else) needs to be loaded by the same class loader. Which means you will not be able to use the jar bundling typically used to run spring boot applications.

Comment: Thank you Klaus. I cannot use this approach because our custom configuration overrides the Spring Boot configuration but Spring boot is still using logback before and after the child() contexts will be created. I am working with Spring extensions, customizing the configuration programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context)` from `logback` in combination with `SiftingAppender`.

Below I'll explain how it should work:

1. `MDC` allows you to have a discriminator which can be used to separate log files based on its value. At this stage you need to do `MDC.put('child-context-key', 'childContextId')` before any top stack method from child context is executed, and `MDC.remove('child-context-key')` after execution.
2. After that you can configure `ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender` which will use `'child-context-key'` value as discriminator to separate your log files.
   example:

   ```xml
   <appender name="CHILD-CONTEXT-SIFT-APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
   <discriminator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator">
       <key>child-context-key</key>
       <defaultValue>defaultChildContextId</defaultValue>
   </discriminator>
   <sift>
       <appender name="CHILD-CONTEXT-SIFT-FILE-APPENDER"
           class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
           <file>/path/to/your/log/file/${child-context-key}.log
           </file>
   </sift>
   </appender>
   ```

Also you can follow [this example](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html) form `logback` which  shows how to configure separate log files for web application modules based on JNDI discriminator.

Comment: I think he wants each child context to log into it's own file, so for this to work he would need to define X number of ShiftAppenders, child-1, child-2, child-3...child-X. Unless he can add the ShiftAppender to logback programatically. You will need to set the MDC before loading the spring context, but if the context uses any executors, you will need to save the MDC (MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()) from the Spring loading thread, so you can set in on the executor threads, which means you need to define the ThreadFactory, or call MDC.setContextMap(saved-MDC) in each runnable run method.

Comment: @Klaus Groenbaek, sorry but you are wrong about several 'SiftAppenders'.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I was reading the documentation but MDC and JNDI are not a valid options because I don't have an app server and MDC is really bad in performance. Additionally, the solution with MDC is not valid because I am looking for something dynamically configurable with the dynamic contexts. MDC is good when you have few messages or thread separation but the child context is quite big with dozens of LOG traces.

Comment: @crm86 example with JNDI just shows how to use `SiftAppender` with `discriminator`, probably  I should not give such an example. You don't need app server or some other specific environment for `MDC`. You can use it even without `thread separation` like I did. For example if you have some `entry points` in your `child contexts` then you can wrap such beans with `AOP` around proxy and manage `MDC` before and after method execution.

Comment: @SergeyBespalov, you are right, I miss understood how they were configured.

Comment: @crm86, why do you think MDC are bad for performance. If you use Log4J it maps to a ThreadLocal map (I assume it does the same in Logback), and I doubt you will find that slow, if you are already using Spring. It's like refusing to use PersistanceUnit and Transactional (annotations) in Spring, and create/manage your own EntityManagers and transactions. Which may technically be faster, but will take 3 time longer to implement, and you will probably make more mistakes.